# Forma correcta de llamar un metodo de otra clase PHP LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, class, controller

Bien, tengo un problema, mas que todo estoy haciendo limpieza de mi codigo.

```
$general_controller = new GeneralController();
$user_data = $general_controller->userData();
```

Estoy llamando a un metodo de otra clase, este es el codigo que utilizo. Primero invoco una nueva instancia de la clase y luego en esa clase apunto a el motodo que quiero.
Me gustaria saber si existe alguna forma de hacerlo directamente en una sola linea y no en dos.

Comment: `$user_data=(new GeneralController())->userData();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si dices que

```
$general_controller = new GeneralController();
```

Entonces nada te impide hacer:

```
$user_data = new GeneralController()->userData();
```

Ahora bien, toma en cuenta que si tu función no te aporta nada más como el objeto al que representa entonces planteate volver estático al método que invocas. En cuyo caso sería asi:

```
$user_data = GeneralController::userData();
```

Como nota, aclarar que tu pregunta no tiene nada de Laravel, pero es algo que veras mucho ahí. De hecho si analizas sus controladores verás que implementa métodos estáticos por defecto, aunque en un futuro implique un alto acoplamiento. Pero eso es otro tema...